# Issue Pinging with Python Script Running as Cron Job

Tags: python, cron

I wrote a Python script to periodically ping network devices to ensure they are connected. My pinging code is as follows:

```
response = os.system('ping -q -c 5 ' + ip_address)
```

This works fine when I run it manually, however, when I run it as a cron job I get the response:

```
sh: ping: command not found
```

I have tried having the cron job run the program as both a packaged application which I created using pyinstaller, and directly as a Python script. Regardless, I get the same error for both (and the correct result when I run either manually).

Comment: `which ping` if youre on unix then use that full path to ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by specifying '/sbin/ping' as the command.